# Display PHP image by URL

Tags: php, image, url

I have this php code (image.php):

```
if($_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] == 'site.tld') {

    header('Content-type: image/jpeg');
    echo file_get_contents("image1.jpg");

} else {

    header('Content-type: image/jpeg');
    echo file_get_contents("image2.jpg");

}
```

*This page (`image.php`) is hosted on `site.tld`;

Now...  This code will be called by `<img src='http://site.tld/image.php' />`.

I'd like to dispay `image1.jpg` if image is called on `site.tld` and `image2.jpg` if not.

That code displays `image1.jpg` whatever domain name where code is called.

Any solutions ? Thanks.

Edit: The output of `$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']` is `site.tld` (my server) on any websites...

That's the problem because the script not works properly.

Comment: Can you post a 'error_log(print_r( $_SERVER, true ))'?

Comment: There is no errors. Problem is that code displays always image1.jpg whatever domain name where code is called.

Comment: Please, Show us the echo $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] result and check the if condition.

Comment: try it with function: `imagecreatefromjpeg`

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
    $imgPath = "image1.jpg";

    if(stripos($_SERVER["HTTP_REFERER"], 'http://site.tld/')=== false){

       $imgPath = "image2.jpg";

    }

    //echo $_SERVER["HTTP_REFERER"]."<br/>";
    //echo $imgPath."<br/>";

    header('Content-type: image/jpeg');
    echo file_get_contents($imgPath);
```

Other option (based on PWhite comments) :

All calls you make from http://site.tld/ add a querystring key, and then evaluates this data too.

Inside site.tld :

```
<img src='http://site.tld/image.php?myfookey=secret' />
```

Outside site.tld :

```
<img src='http://site.tld/image.php' />
```

image.php

```
$imgPath = "image1.jpg";

if (!(isset($_REQUEST["myfookey"]) &&  $_REQUEST["myfookey"] == 'secret')){
    $imgPath = "image2.jpg";
} 

header('Content-type: image/jpeg');
echo file_get_contents($imgPath);
```

Comment: From the PHP documentation: "The address of the page (if any) which referred the user agent to the current page. This is set by the user agent. Not all user agents will set this, and some provide the ability to modify HTTP_REFERER as a feature. In short, it cannot really be trusted."

Comment: Yes, something like that :)
But this example has some errors.
There is an alternative?

Comment: Not "physical" errors. I mean some "bugs". Eg: From site2.tld : right click > view image, and image is now displayed on site1.tld but it remains the same.

Comment: sorry, I do not quite understand. If you navigate from Server site2.tld or site1.tld the image you show is image2.jpg? To be sure to uncomment the echos and check if some data is wrong

Comment: I added another alternative, please let me know if you have solved @PWhite

Comment: That would work, but your key would have to be time-dependant, since anyone can open the source and read the key - i.e. the call to the image file would have to be done within a certain timeframe of the page opening. Perhaps `image.php?key=1351134201.hash` where hash is some function of the time, and the image file checks both that the time is within some threshold (say one minute) and that the hash for the time is correct.

Answer (score 1):

That is because

```
$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']
```

shows the name of *your* server (i.e. the server that executes the PHP).

What you want is the URL of the page that contains `<img src='http://site.tld/image.php' />` and I'm not sure the client's browser sends such information to your server.

/edit: If you're trying to prevent third party websites from showing your picture, you want to do that at the server configuration level, e.g. http://www.davidairey.com/stop-image-theft-hotlinking-htaccess/

Comment: Most of the time it does, as `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']` but this can be spoofed.

Comment: The output of `$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']` is site.tld (my server) in all websites... Looking for a way to take the current url using the picture.

Answer (score 0):

First off, check the `$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']` output for the if condition.
Then use `readfile()` instead of `file_get_contents()`.

Comment: The output of `$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']` is site.tld (my server) in another websites... That's the problem because the script not works properly.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Apache, try setting `UseCanonicalName Off` in your virtual host config (probably need to reload/restart Apache).